# JavaScript to check req fields on button click

Tags: javascript

I need to check all fields have values on click of button.

The button already has a command but I need to check / run through the page for required fields.

On find a blank required field then display message else continue with button next command.

If possible, maybe something that continues check on the form & display text this is required before making button visible?

Answer (score 2):

- jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate
- Prototype: http://tetlaw.id.au/view/blog/really-easy-field-validation-with-prototype/

If you use either of those libraries, it's already written. Otherwise, look at their implementations and roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript form Validation](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)  check this out readly baked just learn it and use according to your requirement .

Just for validating a form  its not a good  to include entire framework.

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/default.asp)  to start with as a beginner to understand the above baked one , Next time you can write your own. :)

Hope it helps !